# Azure blob container listBlobs to fetch files with a specific extension in java

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I've a java code where I list blobs and filter in for loop to fetch only files with a specific extension. Is there a way to query/request container to return just blobs with specific extension? I don't want to loop through all the blobs in the container to do this.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to query/request container to return just blobs with
>   specific extension?

Unfortunately no. You can't query blob storage to return blobs with a particular extension.

> I don't want to loop through all the blobs in the container to do
>   this.

If you're using Storage REST API, that's the only way to do it. You will need to list blobs in the container and then loop through the blobs and do the filtering based on extension (or any other criteria) on the client side.

**Possible Solution**

One possible solution would be to use `Azure Search Service` and have your blob metadata indexed there. Then you should be able to search for a particular extension and get the list of blobs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ListBlobsOptions() with setPrefix to filter based on prefix as shown below

```
ListBlobsOptions options=new ListBlobsOptions();
options.setPrefix("<<prefix>>");
Duration fromDays = Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("containerName");
for (BlobItem blobItem : containerClient.listBlobs(options,fromDays)) {
            System.out.println("\t" + blobItem.getName());
}
```

Comment: The last parameter to **listBlobs**l is timeout and not **lfromDays **l

```
    public PagedIterable<BlobItem> listBlobs(ListBlobsOptions options, Duration timeout) {
        return this.listBlobs(options, null, timeout);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is all you need

```
BlobContainer.ListBlobs(prefix, useFlatBlobListing: true, blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.None)
.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>()
.Where(x=> x.Name.EndsWith(".json"));
```

The `prefix` is just a partial path where search.
The result is an `IEnumerable<CloudBlockBlob>`.